# Onde obter um assembly do compilador Roslyn?

Tags: .net, .net-compiler-platform

Onde posso obter um `Assembly` (`.dll`) que contém o `CodeDom` com o provedor do `.NET Compiler` "`Roslyn`"? Já tentei baixar uma versão aqui e ela esta com muitos bugs, incluindo desempenho péssimo e problemas na execução do `Assembly`.

Comment: Veja se é isto o que procura: [CodeDOM Providers for .NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn"](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estou usando o [pacote que está no Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis) sem problemas, lembrando que ainda é um prerelease. Pode acompanhar o desenvolvimento [no GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn).

Se estiver usando o Visual Studio, abra prompt de comando do nuget e execute:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis -Pre
```

Se quiser baixar direto na pasta, baixe o nuget em http://nuget.org/nuget.exe e execute (os assemblies serão baixados para a mesma pasta que o nuget.exe estiver rodando):

```
nuget.exe Install Microsoft.CodeAnalysis -Pre
```

Esse é um pacotão de todos os seguintes assemblies, você pode baixá-los separadamente e ter parte da funcionalidade:

- "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" (compilador C# + serviços)
- "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces" (compilador VB + serviços)
- "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilers" (ambos compiladores)
- "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" (somente compilador C#)
- "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic (somente compilador VB)

Comment: Não vejo ela sendo referida no CodeDom...